# java if condition == false vs ! operator

Tags: java, if-statement, java-7

when i was looking code of my colleague, i came across below code, which makes me think

```
if((a == d && b < c) == false){
}
```

but i have seen people use ***!*** operator more often instead of checking for Boolean value ***== false***

i don't see anything wrong in the code, but just want to know which is better way doing it. i have searched over Google for an answer, but i didn't get any helpful information.

Comment: Probably is just a matter of personal preference. I personally would use the `!` as I find it much more readable.

Comment: This is personal understanding, as this says If this & this NOT and show clear meaning shows by false

Answer (score 3):

Indeed one sometimes sees == boolean.

```
BAD STYLE                 GOOD STYLE
c == false      <=>       !c
c != true

c == true       <=>       c
c != false
```

This might be due to `!` not being very recognizable (a `not` keyword would be clearer).
But in general it seems to be a perception problem: thinking "c is false", adding to the boolean values true and false a special (value-like) meaning.

It is *bad* style, as it shows a missing mental negation jump, which just *could* be a sign of not being good at boolean logic. As in:

```
if ((a == d && b < c) == false) {
if (!(a == d && b < c)) {
if (a != d || b >= c) {
```

P.S.

Debatable, though `c == true` is objectively absolute redundant, and `c != false` reeks of two negations.

Answer (score 0):

There is no performance difference, you can use what you think it is better. Mostly == false or == true is used by C programmers. I personally use !.

Comment: Most programmers I have seen using this construct never had any C experience. Besides, C programmers would use if (false == var), since in C the compiler would silently accept an assignment in an if statement, like if (var = false), assigning the value instead of comparing. Putting the constant first makes the compiler complain, because you can not assign *to* a constant.

Answer (score 0):

What is the point of redundant use of `boolean`. ?

So to check the `true` condition we can use

```
 if(a == d && b < c){
 }
```

Now you realize we can use

```
 if(!(a == d && b < c)){
 }
```

for not `true` condition.